# On strong convergence of Sum of square of spacings

Tags: probability

I need the proof of strong convergene of

$$(n+1)\sum_{i=1}^n W_i^2$$ as $n ‎\rightarrow‎ \infty,$

where $W_1, W_2, \dots W_n$ are spacings from uniform distribution.

Thank you anybody in advance

Comment: Um, you said sum till $n$ right? This is a finite sum, why would it *not* be convergent?

Comment: @Sabyasachi When $n\to\infty$, of course.

Comment: @Did ah. why can't we just have the $\infty$ on the summation sign?

Comment: @Sabyasachi What are you talking about?

Comment: I meant why can't we just write $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty W_i^2$$ I am just nitpicking.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Not sure which model you are talking about.

Comment: @Did nothing. nevermind. I was not actually talking about solving the problem, just why the OP wrote $n$ instead of $\infty$. or is it not allowed to write $\infty$ here for some reason?

Comment: @Sabyasachi Apparently you still did not get why the $n$th sum must have $n$ terms. You might want to have a look at my answer.

Comment: @Did after reading your answer I did, (the upvote is mine :) )

Answer (score 2):

The *spacings* are defined as follows. Let $(X_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n-1}$ denote an i.i.d. sample, uniform on $(0,1)$, and $(X_{(k)}^n)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n-1}$ the ordered sample, almost surely defined by the two conditions
$$
\{X_{(k)}^n\mid1\leqslant k\leqslant n-1\}=\{X_{k}\mid1\leqslant k\leqslant n-1\},
$$
and
$$
X_{(1)}^n\lt X_{(2)}^n\lt\cdots\lt X_{(n-1)}^n.
$$
The spacings of the sample $(X_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n-1}$ are the random variables $(W_k^n)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ defined by 
$$
W_k^n=X_{(k)}^n-X_{(k-1)}^n,
$$
where, by convention,
$$
X_{(0)}^n=0,\qquad X_{(n)}^n=1.
$$
The question at hand considers
$$
V_n=\sum_{k=1}^n(W_k^n)^2.
$$
It happens that, for every $k$,
$$
E((W_k^n)^2)=\frac2{n(n+1)},
$$
hence 
$$
E(V_n)=\frac2{n+1},
$$
and $V_n\to0$ in $L^1$. If furthermore the random variables $(V_n)$ are built using the same infinite sequence $(X_n)_{n\geqslant1}$, then one computes $V_{n+1}$ from $V_n$ by replacing the length $w^2$ of one interval defining $V_n$ by $u^2+(w-u)^2$, for some $u$ in $(0,w)$. Since $u^2+(w-u)^2\leqslant w^2$ for every $u$ in $(0,w)$, $V_{n+1}\leqslant V_n$ almost surely, hence $V_n\to0$ almost surely.

Comment: I appreciate your kind help. please introduce me a reference for the last statement if possible.

Comment: V n+1 ⩽V n   almost surely, then V n →0  in L 1 implies

Comment: V_n+1 ⩽V_n almost surely, then V_n →0 in L1 implies V_n→0 almost surely.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem

Comment: Is it possible to conclude that (n+1) V_n converges to 2 almost surely?

Comment: New question? Then new post.

Comment: I miss the coefficinet n+1 in my last question. I need the strong convergence for $(n+1)V_n$. Thanks in advance

Comment: Dear Did, Would you please answer my question concerning strong convergence of $(n+1)\sum_{i=1}^n (W_i^n)^2$. I think the answer is 2 (Degenerate at 2), but I can't show that.